# Embedding / exporting PowerPoint presentations to Plone web site

Tags: plone, powerpoint, slideshow

What are my options to embed private PowerPoint presentations on Plone site

- Presentations would be behind Plone log-in
- Integrate some sort of presentation viewer which can input PPT presentations
- Preferably have own content type for the presentations where one could include necessary Javascript and other components needed to integrate the viewer
- Presentations would be viewable directly in a browser (Flash, Javascript, IFRAME any solution accetable as long as it is cross-platform)
- File converter (thru PDF?) or external service (slideshare.com) can be used, as long as data stays private

In the worst case is to have MS Office scripting which exports presentations as PNGs, but still one would need the viewer library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a product called collective.documentviewer that is able to convert these into a viewable format in plone.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.documentviewer/1.3a1

Can convert word, powerpoint, excel, maybe others. Uses the document cloud software http://www.documentcloud.org/home.

Comment: If using without plone.app.async, use the latest release not the one listed on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case: You can "save as" many jpeg-s or png-s by selection file-save as. No scripts needed for this.

Comment: You still need view these things on a web site. And for that, you need some sort of a viewer Javascript. And you still need to upload, arrange, etc. files on the server.

Comment: There are plenty of "slideshow" addons for Plone that provide nice controls for viewing a batch of images.

Comment: But you don`t need to write complicated code for export jpeg-s.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be too easy, but you could use LibreOffice to convert presentations to Flash-animations and provide JavaScript-controls for those. Of course, this would require LibreOffice to be found on the server. [Unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/unoconv) may provide helpful examples for how to use LibreOffice's Python-bindings.

Comment: Does not need to be on the server, we can preprocess files locally before uploading.

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked into this closely, but per http://blog.slideshare.net/2007/11/05/the-wait-of-over-introducing-private-sharing-of-slideshows-on-slideshare/, it does appear that slideshare.net supports private slideshows, which apparently can be embedded in a private page.  So this might be a simple approach that outsources the hard parts while retaining privacy.